# Android - drawing a line

Tags: android, line, draw

I want to draw a line on the screen usign touch listener, but when I try to draw line again, it erases the previous line. I am using the code below.

I am unable to find a solution to the problem. Please help.

```
public class Drawer extends View
{
     public Drawer(Context context)
     {
         super(context);
     }

     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
     {
         Paint p = new Paint();
         p.setColor(colordraw);
         canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2 , y2, p);
         invalidate();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can draw a line using canvas object but u r trying to draw second line using bitmap object try to draw with canvas object

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)

 {
     Paint p = new Paint();
     p.setColor(colordraw);
     p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
     canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2 , y2, p);
     canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2 , y2, p);
     invalidate();
 }
```

Comment: originally it was,
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
     {
         Paint p = new Paint();
         p.setColor(colordraw);
         canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2 , y2, p);
         invalidate();
     }

but whenever OnDraw is triggered, it erasing the previous line.. i want to keep the 1st line and draw a 2nd line using touch listeners...